# error "No handles with labels found to put in legend."

Tags: python, plot, label, legend

```
x = datasetB1780v1["Settlement_Period"]
y1 = datasetB1780v1["Imbalance_Quantity_(MWh)"]
y2 = datasetB1780v1["Insufficient_balance_Price_Amount"]
y3 = datasetB1780v1["Excess_balance_Price_Amount"]+30

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(x, y1, 'green')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y2,'black',label = 'black',)
ax2.plot(x, y3,'yellow',label = 'yellow')
ax2.plot(np.nan, 'green', label = 'green')
ax1.legend(loc=0)


ax1.set_xlabel('Settlement_Period')
ax1.set_ylabel('Imbalance_Quantity', color='green')
ax2.set_ylabel('Insufficient/Excess_balance_Price_Amount', color='b')

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(x)+1, 1))
plt.legend()
```

I have put the handles, why is python giving me this error?

Besides do you know a better way of creating the legends for this code, I am looking for a more elegant way of plotting the legend

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The warning you are getting is because of the line `ax1.legend(loc=0)`. If you remove that, it should be fine. You have the `plt.legend()`, which should show the legend with what matplotlib thinks is the best location Below is the plot you will get with your code and some random dates and Y-values. The legend, however is visible...

[image]

Regarding the legend options, if you don't enter the colors (for eg: `ax1.plot(x, y1)` etc.), the colors will be picked up by default. That is possibly one of the simplest ways. But, if you need to change the location of the box, outline, font, text, etc. you will need to add more options. You can find more information on legends [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) and many other locations.